# What is neither material nor immaterial, is what?

Tags: self

Every history of a world begins to be written after the creation of this world, when a “brilliant mind” appears that realizes it, thus a language and a civilization appear. From this, one fantasizes how this world was created. And this story to which I write is also about this, how the world we live in came about, however, from an introspective and inductive perspective, from the inside out.

And this is, from the part that comes from within us, the most interesting part. Some old Greek and Chinese sayings about knowing yourself have already surfaced in this search, but they are just sayings and it is not easy to find more elaborate thoughts about what self-knowledge properly is.

We could get to know the world or this story in a deductive way, from the outside in. However, this one is even more difficult to resolve, because in the first place, if we don't know anything about ourselves, much less will we know or have discernment as to what we are not. We will then resolve from within ourselves, in an in-depth study, of what we are.
There are several disciplines that elaborate this, psychology, philosophy, religion, neuroscience, among others. We will use some of them to elaborate something very interesting, such as birth. There are biblical texts that say that we already existed before we were born in this physical world, because we already exist in the mind of God. In psychology, we are what we think we are. For now, I think about writing, I'm a writer, another time I'll be something else. By Philosophy, Medicine, Biology, we are mere animals with specific qualities.

Special qualities like the human mind, capable of creating language and civilization, in terms of capacity and organization.

However, writing this broadly, as dealing with all of us, is a little tricky, as there are cultures different from mine and thoughts different from mine. But one thing that denies any culture and thought is the way we came to the world, by birth, starting from it will be a good way to get to know each other, nothing so detailed in the biological aspect, such as embryonic development and biology terms, none of that, let's go start with the emergence of consciousness, the sense of alertness, which makes us know that we are alive.
It would be interesting here, if we look to neuroscience to explain to us what our current knowledge of consciousness is.

Our brain, also known as the central nervous system (CNS), does not see, does not feel. In fact, it just processes all the information that comes from outside through the peripheral nervous system, vision, touch, taste, smell and hearing. The CNS absorbs these electrical pulses from the sensations of the PNS and converts them into a 3-dimensional spatial picture, a sculpture of the world that has reach, frozen, stopped in time. In the next instant, the CNS generates another frame, which is different from the previous one and compares it with the previous one and repeats this process throughout life, cumulatively and in this medium, between one frame and another, it forms a post-processing reaction. This reaction can become a movement, a speech, a thought.

This is how we process things around us from birth and react to them. But what is really ours? Is the reaction, a reflection of how the world welcomes us, really who we are or a mere external reflection, like a ball coming and going in a game of ping-pong?
Since we cannot say that what we touch is what we feel, because we are feeling something outside of us by touch, when listening, we hear something outside, and practically everything we feel comes from outside. Of course, as I write, I look at my hands writing and I may even think that I am creating this text, because it is my fingers typing and my thoughts transcribing what I feel out, but is this really who I am? No, and the culprit is a cascade of events that created our civilization and culture, along with language.

Language does not belong to us either, it is not something that arises within us and expands to the world, in fact, it is an organized cascade of information coming from a primordial event that generated language, civilization and we are as if we were following a script already written, determined by posthumous past reactions, for you rarely see anyone like a dizzy cockroach, as if poisoned, running around. Also as some biblical texts say, “It is not for man to walk in his footsteps”. But, in fact, there is something that we cannot deny, our language does not come from within us either, as soon as the formation of thought, neither does it. The language in the form of words that thought produces cannot be exactly what we are. So what are we really?

Could we say that we are a block of clumps of atoms, organized by a higher order of degree, our DNA? It is known that our body is ordered by DNA, which is a code based on 4 enzymes and that forms our structure, an intelligent code of pure information. But again, too, our atoms are exchanged almost completely every 7 years, as most of the cells in our body are exchanged, being replaced by new ones, with rare exceptions.

What are we really? Mere information?

Again, we cannot attribute the information to ourselves, as it uses a language that was not created by us, the entire organization of a language has already been fully structured so that roots and radicals, prefixes and suffixes, generate new words, which are not they exist now in our time and someone will generate them in the future, but the synthesis already exists.

If we are neither material like our bodies nor immaterial like information, what is left?

Comment: I can't answer your question, but you might want to read this, as it may help https://iep.utm.edu/integrated-information-theory-of-consciousness/

Comment: Could you possibly pick a single question and ask that?

Comment: But according to [Philosophical dualism](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/descartes/#MinRel) there are only two "substances": the material one and the immaterial one, the Mind.

Comment: Why does the fact that the information in our minds didn't originate entirely in ourselves somehow imply that our identity cannot be defined in terms of information? You haven't really given an argument as to why something has to originate in the self to be part of the self.

Comment: Those who go beyond dualism assert besides the sensible or physical and the mental or imaginary,  there might be physical-like realms such as Plato's Realm of Forms or real possible worlds, etc that our mind is in "contact" or has "access to".